# Is this a correct sentence: "It can be more expedient to supplement the diet rather than improve it."?

Tags: adjectives, determiners

**Question**

While there may be other issues I'm specifically interested in the use of the word "expedient". To me this sentence sounds off, can something be "more expedient" or is something always either expedient or not?

**Context**

I'm trying to express that sometimes when there is a lack of a certain nutrient in a persons diet the faster and easier solution in the short term to is to supplement the missing nutrient rather than spend the time finding good sources of foods the person enjoys eating.

If you have any feedback on my english or grammar in this post I'm also interested in that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expedient  = (of an action) convenient and practical although possibly improper or immoral. E.g. "either side could break the agreement if it were expedient to do so."

As a noun = a means of attaining an end, especially one that is convenient but possibly improper or immoral. "the current policy is a political expedient" (Source Google).  You may review accordingly.

As for the grammar part, "more...rather than" sounds needing improvement.  It should be "more...than" or "rather...than"

Comment: Thank you :) I now have "It can be more expedient to supplement the diet than to improve it." Is expedient is the wrong word to use here since it doesn't relate to morals? I'm not trying to say the thing is morally wrong, just that it's not a good long term solution.

Comment: @koreus737 There is a point Ram Pillai hinted at but which you have not picked up on.  ‘expedient’ as you are using it is slightly off.  ‘more convenient’, or even ‘less complicated’ or ‘simpler’ would be nearer to what you are trying to express.

Comment: @Tuffy Thank you. I'm trying to understand in what way something must be improper for expedient to be the right word. In my eyes it is improper to supplement the diet when nutritious food is available. But perhaps improper refers more to politeness and decency than what is best for someone. Say for example using a piece of gum in place of blue tac, would that be expedient?

Comment: @ koreus737  Well, I would not use the word 'improper'.  that word has the overtones of behaviours or attitudes associated with lack of integrity or indecency.  'Inappropriate' might be better.  However, there is a way in which the use of the word 'expedient' has become embroiled in storms of political controversy.  'Expedient" has become associated with the idea of bestowing personal or political party advantage.  So it has been acquiring a derogatory aura, where, a few decades ago that would not have been so.